# Accessing bluetooth lower level profiles

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

**Modified after @TJD's answer**

I am writing a Bluetooth app for Android but I've read (and heared) that many Android devices doesn't supports HID Profile. So my question is can I use lower level protocols like L2CAP, GAP, etc.? Are these protocols have some UUID kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

L2CAP is not a profile (the P stands for protocol) and it is part of the core BT specification.  All devices support L2CAP, and profiles such as HID (and nearly all others) sit on top of L2CAP and use L2CAP to send data.  GAP is also mandatory.  You could implement the HID profile by writing your own code that interacts at the GAP and L2CAP interface level.

Comment: If I am going to implement the HID profile of my own, then do I have to do it in the native code, or could it be done in Java itself?